# Problemas de compilación en sublime text 2 con python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, sublimetext

Estoy comenzando con python utilizando Sublime Text 2. Tengo problemas de compilación con el `input` y `raw_input`, obtengo el mismo error de compilación en ambos casos:

> File "C:\Users\Administrador\Documents\prueba de entrada.py", line 2,
>   in 
>       m=input("dame un numero") EOFError: EOF when reading a line [Finished in 0.3s with exit code 1]

El programa compila bien por terminal, ¿cual puede ser el problema?

Comment: Si utilizas windows revisa que sublime text utilice [/CR/LF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11899843/fixing-sublime-text-2-line-endings) como fin de línea (fin de línea tipo windows), también deberás revisar la codificación, si es [utf-8 revisa que sea sin BOM](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/save-as-utf8-without-bom/2984)

Answer (score 1):

se usa raw_input en python 2 y input en python 3.
para saber que versión de python tienes debes de abrir tu terminal o cmd y escribir "python"[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

vas a ver algo como esto, en la segunda linea puedes ver que versión tienes, en esa foto está python 3.